# Add field - value to multidimensional array in php

Tags: php

I have an array of "Deals" objects and I need to add the idApplication field with value to 1 in each supply of the array.

How can I do this?

Thank you!

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://aplicatiuspin.cat/aplicatiu/webServices/views/?v=ofertes/json&idAplicatiu=59&template=none');
$json2 = file_get_contents('https://aplicatiuspin.cat/aplicatiu/webServices/views/?v=ofertes/json&idAplicatiu=55&template=none');
$ofertes = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($ofertes as &$ofert) {
    $ofert["idAplicatiu"]=59;
}
```

Comment: Post your array code or what you tried?

Comment: Hi @BhuneshSatpada,
The code is already set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use code:

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('https://aplicatiuspin.cat/aplicatiu/webServices/views/?v=ofertes/json&idAplicatiu=59&template=none');
$json2 = file_get_contents('https://aplicatiuspin.cat/aplicatiu/webServices/views/?v=ofertes/json&idAplicatiu=55&template=none');
$ofertes = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($ofertes as $key => $ofert ) {
    $ofertes[$key]["idAplicatiu"]=59;
}
?>
```